# Lock mouse/UI until window fully loads vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, locking

I have a large form with many controls that I would like to 'lock' until all the data is loaded. I can't find anything on this out there.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `Form.Shown` event is the one you want to handle. I would put the controls in a disabled state and then enable everything in the `Form.Shown` event handler, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Form1.Shown
    ' Put logic here to enable your form controls here
End Sub
```

Read the MSDN documentation for [Form.Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

On top of what Karl Anderson has mentioned above, you could also set the Mouse Cursor to a different state while the data is loading.

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
' Load data here
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.waitcursor.aspx

Comment: I'd insert Application.DoEvents after setting the wait cursor otherwise it may take a while to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use the **.Enable** method.
Disable the form until your data loads. 
Or you could add a border-less form that says "Loading" on it and once your data is loaded, you can call your main form.
I don't suggest locking the mouse because that's going to annoy your users. Unless it's a full-screen game.

Comment: I use a bright "loading" label over the form and hide it when done. You could update the label caption adding periods every few seconds to show progress if you have control in the thread loading the data, or use a progress bar for that matter.